# gdb guide for the DEBUG user

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am very familiar with `DEBUG.COM` from DOS. I have just gotten the need to use `gdb` but I am stuck. I am sure `gdb` is much more versatile and powerful, but I just need to step through a piece of code (not generated by any particular language) efficiently and with good visibility of registers and selected memory locations.  What are the `gdb` equivalent of DEBUG's:

```
U - unassemble (from select memory location)
D - dump
R - shows (selected) registers
T - executes instruction at current IP
P - step over
```

`gdb` seems to require `run` as the first step before I can even inspect the registers.  But I would like to see what the first instruction is before I want to run. I can't put a break point at the first instruction if I don't know where it is. It's a chicken and egg problem for me. I must be missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know DEBUG, but maybe I can help with your gdb questions.  You're probably best off reading a gdb tutorial, though.  Also you can see more details for any command using the gdb `help` command, e.g., `help disassemble`.

Your questions seem focused on low-level, assembly debugging.  gdb is a multi-level debugger, by which I mean it can work at various levels; I would say that fundamentally it is a source-level debugger, but it can function ok at the assembly level as well.

- `unassemble`.  gdb equivalent is probably `disassemble`.
- `dump`.  I don't know what this does.  If it dumps memory, then you want the gdb `x` command.
- `R`.  Try `info regs`, or you can print just a selected register using the name, like `print $rax`.
- `T`.  To step a single assembly instruction, `si`.
- `P`.  See the gdb `ni` command.

For the first instruction, you need to know some details about the platform.  On Linux the first instruction is at `_start`, so you would `break *_start`.

Comment: I am now debugging a C produced binary.  `si` will stubbornly execute each C source statement and not the current machine instruction.  How do I switch to execute machine instruction?

Comment: `si` does just single step at the instruction level; it's just that gdb prints the current source line with each step.  I don't think this can be disabled, but you can make it also show the instruction as well, with `display/i $pc`.